# Finding potential for F

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let ${\bf{F}} = f(r)(x,y,z)$ where $r = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$. Find an
>   expression for a potential for $\bf{F}$

I'm not sure how to start this question, mostly because I'm unsure of the notation ${\bf{F}} = f(r)(x,y,z)$ and how exactly you can integrate w.r.t $x,y,z$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a radial function $f(r)$ times the position vector $(x,y,z)$. Work backwards. Start with a radial function $\phi(r)$ and compute its gradient.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. Partially because I don't know what I should be differentiating when finding the gradient of a radial function (i.e. whether to do a coordinate change etc.)

Comment: Just jump in and take partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$. Of course, you'll need to use the chain rule.

Comment: So wrt $x$,  $\phi_x = \dfrac{d\phi}{dr} \dfrac{dr}{dx} = x(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2} \dfrac{d\phi}{dr}$ is that the way in which I need to use the chain rule? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, except I would write $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}$.